# Limits and While Loops

Tags: limits, programming

> **Question**: Consider the following program. Does $f(1)=\infty$?
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(i):=&|\text{while } \frac{1}{i}>0\\
> &||i\leftarrow i+1\\
> &|i
> \end{align*}

I would say that $f(1)=\infty$ is a true statement. The program does not terminate, but one could consider the sequence of points $\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ given by $x_i:=\frac{1}{i}$, so that  $\{x_i\}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to the limit $0$ which makes $\underbrace{\frac{1}{i}}_{=0}>0$ false which means $f(1)=\infty$. However, I could be wrong.

Comment: The line $||i\leftarrow i+1$ add 1 to the original variable $i$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what that means. So, $\frac{1}{1}>0$ is true in the beginning so then we add $1$ to $i$ which looking at the precondition we know $\frac{1}{2}>0$ is true. This loop continues over and over until the statement is false.

Comment: For strictly positive inputs $i$, the algorithm never terminates. In fact, the loop criterion $\frac{1}{i}>0$ can be simplified to $i>0$, except that the former is ill-defined when the denominator is zero. For the strictly positive inputs, repeatedly incrementing $i$ by one does not change the fact that $i$ is positive. If we keep the $\frac{1}{i}>0$, for negative integer inputs and the input $0$ (zero), the criterion eventually involves division by zero which is not usually defined. For negative inputs that are not integer, after a number of iterations, $0<i<1$ at which time $i$ is returned.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen For _any_ negative input, integer or not, the iteration fails on the first step because $$-|x|^{-1} < 0$$

Comment: Depends on the programming language most programming languages round the result so $1/n$ might equal $0$ for some $n$.

Comment: Does the line `|i` mean that, in case (1/i) > 0, the function produces `i`?

Comment: Are you talking about the third line down? The program pretty much states the following: have $i$ start out at one. Is $\frac{1}{i}>0$ true or false? If it is true, then add one to $i$ and have this become the new value for $i$ and repeat the last question. If it is false, the value  $i$ is the outputted final value.

Comment: @twalberg You are right, of course. My comment is wrong.

Comment: "If it is false, the value i is the outputted final value." <- in that case, see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2929272/596735) on why 0 (or rather, <1) is the only *impossible* outcome.

Comment: This whole question I have been thinking $\frac{1}{i}$ is my last line when it was just $i$. I decided to leave the question up and running, but I did edit some major points. This is why $f(1)=0$ on everyone's response. I am sorry about that everybody.

Comment: Essentially, you're asking "What does this program do?" but you haven't defined the semantics of the language so the answer could be anything.

Comment: So loops in this way have not been defined before?

Comment: @W.G. Altering the question itself in this way is rather confusing and invalidates certain responses. It would clarify the resulting record if you'd revert the changes.

Comment: Also, mathematics tends to prefer recursion over loops. It'd look more like `f(i):=((1/i) > 0 → f(i+1)) ^ ((1/i) <= 0 → i)` (or something like that, I'm not that familiar with the semantics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final result of the function would depend on the method of division you'd end up using, at least if this function is executed by a computer.

One thing we *can* be sure of, however, is that **the result of f(1) will under no circumstance be 0**.

After all, the input of the function is `1` and the loops keeps **increasing** the value of `i`.

For example, if the function is executed using integer division, `(1 / 2) > 0` would be false, and the function would end up yielding a result.

*However, the result would be `2`, not `0`.*

Therefore, the function either runs out of resources, or returns something larger than 0 - but never 0.

---

Although I'm answering this question as a programmer, rather than as mathematician, the logic remains true whether it be mathematical or programmatic: Even if we assume the loop can run to infinity, and we assume 1 divided by infinity as greater than 0, **the function would produce infinity, not 0**.

Pure logic dictates that `f(1) != 0`, whichever notation is preferred :)

---

Since I'm writing this as a programmer on the internet anyway, I might as well provide proof along with this answer.

I wrote the following snippet:

```
<?php

function f($i) {
    while ((1 / $i) > 0) {
        $i = increase($i);
    }
    return $i;
}

function increase($n) {
    if ($n < 100) {
        return $n + 1;
    }
    return INF;
}
```

(I would have used `if ($n < INT_MAX)` but that results in a 3+ seconds runtime)

Long story short, `assert(f(1) === INF);` passes, and

```
dump(f(1));
```

Is indeed `float(INF)`.

[Run this code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2006209ec07e92587ce806b4118d953c37230bc7)

Comment: I am going to edit the question slightly. So, assuming the loop does go to infinity does imply that $f(1)=\infty$?

Comment: If 1/∞ > 0, then yes.

Comment: ...what I meant is `if !(1/∞ > 0)`, then yes, f(1)=∞

Comment: Actually, [here's](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2006209ec07e92587ce806b4118d953c37230bc7) an example of your function. It's written in php and has the explicit assumption that after 100 comes infinity. Since floating point arithmetic agrees that `!(1 / INF) > 0`, the example indeed produces `float(INF)` when ran.

Comment: What is float(INF) just out of curiosity? Is it just infinity?

Comment: It's the concept of infinity as described by the language the example is ran in :) Floating point arithmetic has its own [concept of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Infinities), which I assume comes pretty close to a mathematically accepted definition.

Answer (score 9):

The only thing we can say here is that $f(1)$ is not defined, or that the program does not terminate for the input $1$.

We cannot say that $f(1)=0$.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the term "total correctness" of the program requires the program to terminate which is often considered in proofs. However, why is that $f(1)$ is not defined in the mathematical sense? Is it required to finite?

Comment: @W.G. $f(1)$ is not defined because $f$ does not terminate for the input $1$. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I am not trying to rock the boat here or anything, but I agree that the program does not terminate. Any computer would say that $f(1)$ makes no sense . However, we know that the loop continues on forever. Every iteration for the NATURAL NUMBERS, can be proved inductively to show that $\frac{1}{i}>0$ is true. Assuming the loop is finite would be wrong. The loop must go on forever. If the loop was finite, the program clearly would not exist as $\frac{1}{i}>0$ would always be true never giving an output. As the loop goes on to infinity, why can't we assume $i$ goes to infinity?

Comment: @W.G. You can if you want to, but then you must specifically state how you evaluate programs that "go to infinity". In mathematics, you can play with whatever tool you want, but you must first decide how to use the tools. Limits are one such rigorous tool for dealing with infinity. Computer programs, as usually defined, are not - so you must expand their definition.

Comment: More or less as an aside, there are cases where we "take limits" when reasoning about computer programs in order to deal with infinite loops. It's an important tool when trying to give denotational semantics for recursively defined functions. I can imagine extending such logic to give a denotational semantics of a language where OPs question is answered yes, but the resulting language would likely be very hard to give an operational semantics for, and of questionable use.

Comment: "Any computer would say that f(1) makes no sense" <- In all probability, any computer would probably consider `f(1) == 0` a true statement, considering the most common course for a computer program in such case is to use either integer or, most likely, float division: with integer division, 1 / 2 = 0 and with float division 1 / lots = eventually considered equal to 0. This argument would not apply were the program written to handle the number as fraction, in which case the program either terminates in a division by zero or by running out of memory.

Comment: "would probably consider f(1) == 0 a true statement" <- actually no, [it never would](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2929272/596735)

Comment: I appreciate your answer. However, I am not looking for what a computer would give. I am looking for a math theoretical reason just focusing on the theory behind the loop, and not on the computer theory like how a computer divides. I should have made that more explicit in the question. I do appreciate the response though.

Comment: @W.G. There's really nothing to argue about here. There is no objective answer. The function certainly does not return 0, we agree on that. The sequence of values taken on by $i$ converges to 0, that's also true. Does the function "equal zero" in some vague, hand-wavy sense? Listen, you put enough finger-quotes around the word "equals" and you can get me to agree to anything. But at the end of the day you're just arguing semantics. What matters is what's objectively true: *no* the function does not return 0, *yes* the sequence of values of $i$ converges to 0. There's nothing more to discuss.

Comment: @JackM: "yes the sequence of values of i converges to 0. " <- Well, the trick part of the question is that the values of i does not converge to 0, but instead to infinity. `1/i` may converge to 0, but *i* itself does not. As I [pointed out earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2929272/596735), the actual value of *i* is an ever-**increasing** value, and therefore will never ever reach zero, nor will it approach zero any less than the original input value.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a funny question. Looks like the best answer is "no." The number $1$ is not in the domain of $f$, because the program doesn't terminate.

It's true that as a human we can see that the in-memory value of $1/i$ is headed toward $0$, but $f$ was never going to return $1/i$, it was going to return $i$, which is headed off to $\infty$. Even if it were going to return $1/i$, the answer still shouldn't be $0$, because the program doesn't terminate and there's no notion of a limiting operation made explicit here.

Answer (score 0):

The function is undefined at $i=1$ since $\not \exists b$ such that $b=f(1)$.

For a formal proof, indicating with $i_k$ the value assumed by $i$ at the $k^{th}$ loop, we can show by induction that $\forall k$

- $i_k\ge 1 \implies \frac 1{i_k}>0$

therefore the loop will never end.

More in general $f(i)$ is undefined for any $i>0$ and $f(i)=i$ for any $i< 0$.

For $i=0$ it depends on how the "while" command returns to the operation $1/0$.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a while-loop, a better programming analogy of limits is the lazy list.

In Haskell:

```
naturals = [1..]
my_limit = [1/n n <- naturals]
take 100 my_limit
```

Outputs:

```
[1.0,0.5,0.3333333333333333,0.25,0.2,0.16666666666666666,0.14285714285714285,0.125,0.1111111111111111,0.1,9.090909090909091e-2,8.333333333333333e-2,7.692307692307693e-2,7.142857142857142e-2,6.666666666666667e-2,6.25e-2,5.8823529411764705e-2,5.555555555555555e-2,5.263157894736842e-2,5.0e-2,4.7619047619047616e-2,4.5454545454545456e-2,4.3478260869565216e-2,4.1666666666666664e-2,4.0e-2,3.8461538461538464e-2,3.7037037037037035e-2,3.571428571428571e-2,3.4482758620689655e-2,3.333333333333333e-2,3.225806451612903e-2,3.125e-2,3.0303030303030304e-2,2.9411764705882353e-2,2.857142857142857e-2,2.7777777777777776e-2,2.702702702702703e-2,2.631578947368421e-2,2.564102564102564e-2,2.5e-2,2.4390243902439025e-2,2.3809523809523808e-2,2.3255813953488372e-2,2.2727272727272728e-2,2.2222222222222223e-2,2.1739130434782608e-2,2.127659574468085e-2,2.0833333333333332e-2,2.040816326530612e-2,2.0e-2,1.96078431372549e-2,1.9230769230769232e-2,1.8867924528301886e-2,1.8518518518518517e-2,1.818181818181818e-2,1.7857142857142856e-2,1.7543859649122806e-2,1.7241379310344827e-2,1.694915254237288e-2,1.6666666666666666e-2,1.639344262295082e-2,1.6129032258064516e-2,1.5873015873015872e-2,1.5625e-2,1.5384615384615385e-2,1.5151515151515152e-2,1.4925373134328358e-2,1.4705882352941176e-2,1.4492753623188406e-2,1.4285714285714285e-2,1.4084507042253521e-2,1.3888888888888888e-2,1.36986301369863e-2,1.3513513513513514e-2,1.3333333333333334e-2,1.3157894736842105e-2,1.2987012987012988e-2,1.282051282051282e-2,1.2658227848101266e-2,1.25e-2,1.2345679012345678e-2,1.2195121951219513e-2,1.2048192771084338e-2,1.1904761904761904e-2,1.1764705882352941e-2,1.1627906976744186e-2,1.1494252873563218e-2,1.1363636363636364e-2,1.1235955056179775e-2,1.1111111111111112e-2,1.098901098901099e-2,1.0869565217391304e-2,1.0752688172043012e-2,1.0638297872340425e-2,1.0526315789473684e-2,1.0416666666666666e-2,1.0309278350515464e-2,1.020408163265306e-2,1.0101010101010102e-2,1.0e-2]
```

In Python:

```
import itertools
naturals = itertools.count(1)
my_limit = (1/n for n in naturals)
list(itertools.islice(my_limit, 100))
```

Outputs:

```
[1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25, 0.2, 0.16666666666666666, 0.14285714285714285, 0.125, 0.1111111111111111, 0.1, 0.09090909090909091, 0.08333333333333333, 0.07692307692307693, 0.07142857142857142, 0.06666666666666667, 0.0625, 0.058823529411764705, 0.05555555555555555, 0.05263157894736842, 0.05, 0.047619047619047616, 0.045454545454545456, 0.043478260869565216, 0.041666666666666664, 0.04, 0.038461538461538464, 0.037037037037037035, 0.03571428571428571, 0.034482758620689655, 0.03333333333333333, 0.03225806451612903, 0.03125, 0.030303030303030304, 0.029411764705882353, 0.02857142857142857, 0.027777777777777776, 0.02702702702702703, 0.02631578947368421, 0.02564102564102564, 0.025, 0.024390243902439025, 0.023809523809523808, 0.023255813953488372, 0.022727272727272728, 0.022222222222222223, 0.021739130434782608, 0.02127659574468085, 0.020833333333333332, 0.02040816326530612, 0.02, 0.0196078431372549, 0.019230769230769232, 0.018867924528301886, 0.018518518518518517, 0.01818181818181818, 0.017857142857142856, 0.017543859649122806, 0.017241379310344827, 0.01694915254237288, 0.016666666666666666, 0.01639344262295082, 0.016129032258064516, 0.015873015873015872, 0.015625, 0.015384615384615385, 0.015151515151515152, 0.014925373134328358, 0.014705882352941176, 0.014492753623188406, 0.014285714285714285, 0.014084507042253521, 0.013888888888888888, 0.0136986301369863, 0.013513513513513514, 0.013333333333333334, 0.013157894736842105, 0.012987012987012988, 0.01282051282051282, 0.012658227848101266, 0.0125, 0.012345679012345678, 0.012195121951219513, 0.012048192771084338, 0.011904761904761904, 0.011764705882352941, 0.011627906976744186, 0.011494252873563218, 0.011363636363636364, 0.011235955056179775, 0.011111111111111112, 0.01098901098901099, 0.010869565217391304, 0.010752688172043012, 0.010638297872340425, 0.010526315789473684, 0.010416666666666666, 0.010309278350515464, 0.01020408163265306, 0.010101010101010102, 0.01]
```

Your question might be interpreted to ask what the last element of such a lazy list is.